# SVG Line not drawing at some co-ordinates

Tags: html, xml, svg

SVG Line at this point isn't drawing line at this coordinates (`x1="200" x2="0" y1="200" y2="200"`) . This problem happens only in Firefox. What mistake did I make?

```
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
          <line x1="0" x2="200" y1="0" y2="0" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2"></line>
<line x1="200" x2="200" y1="0" y2="200" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2"></line>
<line x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="200" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2"></line>
<line x1="200" x2="0" y1="200" y2="200" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2"></line>
        </svg>
```

Comment: I see a red outline rectangle on Firefox 19. Is that not what you see?

Comment: No, There wasn't  bottom line when I checked

Comment: Have you zoomed in or out inadvertently?

Comment: no, I haven't. y this Firefox always sucks?